# Facebook Open Graph scraping error for SSL website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ssl

Since we've made our website SSL secure and PCI compliant, Facebook open graph scraper can no longer read the open graph meta tags. Here's a sample of our code for the meta tags in the {head} of https://FantasyDecathlon.com

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="576816272427310" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="223653" />
<meta property="og:title" content="FantasyDecathlon: The world series of fantasy sports" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="The FantasyDecathlon"  />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://fantasydecathlon.com/img/logo.jpg" />
```

But Facebook Open Graph scraper gives the error:

> Curl Error : SSL_CONNECT_ERROR Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to fantasydecathlon.com:443

and

> Object at URL 'https://fantasydecathlon.com/' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.

And when we click on the link for what the Facebook Open Graph scraper sees for our URL, it returns null.

For our SSL setup, we would prefer not to loosen the restrictions since it's important for us to maintain PCI compliance.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked SSL labs to see if you're site has any issues: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

Comment: Yes, https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=fantasydecathlon.com - I'm not sure what can cause problem for facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! We made a number of updates, but we believe the fix was a bug with our DNS records. We removed a couple of duplicates and we added new records with directly to our 2 server nodes.

Thank you everyone for your help!